# typescript compile error in body-parser.d.ts: Could not find symbol 'Buffer'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am getting the following compile errors in body-parser.d.ts when compiling my typescript file.

error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'Buffer'.
error TS2094: The property 'RequestHandler' does not exist on value of type 'express'.

And I have the following lines in my app.ts file.

```
///<reference path='../Scripts/typings/node/node.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='../Scripts/typings/body-parser/body-parser.d.ts'/>

import express = require('express');
import bodyParser = require('body-parser');
import http = require('http');
import path = require('path');
```

Why am I getting the errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `express.d.ts` as it is required for `body-parser.d.ts` : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/body-parser/body-parser.d.ts#L6

Very unlikely to be a bug in the Definitions as DefinitelyTyped is compiled to make sure that such errors don't make it to users like yourself.

Comment: I do have express.d.ts and I added the reference path after node.d.ts, but still same errors. Also looking at body-parser.d.ts, it already had the reference path to express.d.ts. Any other ideas?

Comment: Never mind. My node.d.ts and express.d.ts files were outdated. After copying the latest versions from DefinitelyTyped my ts file compiles fine. Thanks!